# i'm getting this error from a '$_POST['phone']' unexpected '' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) for a insert on mysql

Tags: php, string, insert

i'm new on stackfloww but allways i found solutions here. today is my first questions. the problem i have is this:

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\zupa\guardar.php on line 32
```

i read php documentation and is for my string is from a input with just acept numbers. i make it with the next function

```
   $(document).ready(function (){
   $('#2').keyup(function (){
   this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

now the problem is te sintaxis and iam on the line of craziness.

this is my code

```
<?php  




     //la funcion para conectarse cn la base de datos 




     //conectado con la base de datos

  include('conexion.php');
  $conexion=conectar();







     // agarro via post las variables y las conecto al mysql



             mysql_query('INSERT INTO mensajes(name,phone,comment,rate) VALUES('.$_POST['name']'
                                                                               '$_POST['phone']'
                                                                               '$_POST['comment']'
                                                                               '$_POST['rate']')') 
             or die(mysql_error());

             echo "dato guardado";
```

?>

and the error is in the line 32 wich is

`'$_POST['phone']'`

thank for any help!

Comment: definitely your quotes and SQL injection heaven

Comment: missing commas missing dots

Comment: frightened him off just before I pressed the post button

Comment: @Dagon oh sure, make it look worse

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry bro :-)

Comment: @Dagon head of the Olympic comittee. So, not giving out flowers with those gold medals?

Comment: Oh a dup, should have checked first. Naughty me

Comment: @Fred-ii- no one mentioned the use of mysql_*

Comment: some of us have a bookmark list of dupes :-)

Comment: @Dagon You were to quick with the dup for anybody to get round to it. Hehe

Comment: This thing requires a master seamstress who doubles as a coder. It's "stitched" with holes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah he takes all the fun out of us poor scabs who "search" for dupes. He's got "the list" tucked away in his lab.

Comment: @Dagon Nah, there are bigger problems with this. You said it yourself way back when. You can do just as well with `mysql_` if you know how to keep the snakes and roaches out of the pick-ah-nick basket.

Comment: Juan if you are still stuck: http://codepad.viper-7.com/05gxcP